# Bounded function

Tags: convergence-divergence

${f_n}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $\Bbb R$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly **on every finite interval $[a,b]$**. If each $f_n$ is bounded, is it true that $f$ must be bounded?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample:

$f_n(x) = |x|$ if $|x| < n$
$f_n(x) = n$ otherwise

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by smoothing out?

Comment: @David: Thanks $-$ I missed the continuity requirement. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but this doesn't converge uniformly

Comment: @Marc: It converges uniformly on every bounded interval.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read carefully enough...

Comment: @Marc: That makes two of us :-)

Comment: Note that it is true if $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly.

Comment: Could you explain why this converges on every bounded interval, but not uniformly?

Comment: @kiwifruit: $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on every bound interval, but not on $\mathbb R$. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Marc: Yes of course.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand the difference between the two. Can't we say R is a combination of many bounded intervals?

Comment: @kiwifruit: You think that if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on every bounded interval, then it must converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$? Then you must sit down and do some thinking, perhaps with my counterexample in mind.

Comment: It is quite straightforward to prove if the convergence is uniformly. Use the definition that in that case for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, we know.

Comment: It was intended for Kiwifruit;)

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a hard time picturing the counterexample graphically, so it's a bit difficult for me to see what the difference is.

Comment: @kiwifruit: I don't see what more we can usefully say. Sooner or later, you have to think things out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is NO. For example, Let $f(x)=x$, $f_n(x)=x$ if $-n\leq x\leq n$, $f_n(x)=-n$ if $ x\leq -n$, and $f_n(x)=n$ if $ x\geq n$.